# How do I display directories first using git ls-files

Tags: git, git-ls-files

I am looking for something similar to the `--group-directories-first` parameter of `ls` for the command

```
git ls-files
```

Normally, the output is alphabetically sorted and looks like this:

```
anotherfile.c
directory/file.c
file.c
```

I want it to look like this:

```
directory/file.c
anotherfile.c
file.c
```

Comment: Pipe the output through a script that sorts it into the order you prefer, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

That does not seem to be supported (or even discussed in the [Git mailing list](https://marc.info/?l=git&w=2&r=3&s=ls-files%20group%20directories%20first&q=b))

Only some kind of command alias/output processing would return the desired output (like calling the command twice, once including "/" for getting all the path with folders, once excluding "/" for getting files only)